# Updated Tor Browser to the latest version and lost all scrapbooked records. Anyway to find the records?

Tags: help

I updated tor browser to the latest version that does not support ScrapBook X. It looks like I lost all my scrapbooked records. Is there any way to find the records? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install scrapbook on Waterfox or Tor portable portable.Install Waterfox first. You will have to go hunting for the old scrapbook files. They may be in data profile scrapbook. Retrieve the file named scrapbook and put it on your desktop. Once you locate the scrapbook files which are numbered with date codes you can open them in other browsers. After you have verified these are the correct files make a copy of the scrapbook folder just in case. Then At the top of the scrapbook bar in Waterfox click tools options save data to the new scrapbook location. You may have to uninstall the old Tor to get portable Tor working. This is not going to be fun some one has went to war with scrapbook. There will be script errors you will have to click continue on and the scrapbook information will stay on top blocking out other open windows until the process finishes. I recommend once you get Waterfox or Tor working like you want it make multiple copies of the program and store them elsewhere.